# stored procedure with cursor in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor, return

Can I use Cursor with stored procedure in MySQL?   And can I receive the output values from it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE curdemo()
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE a CHAR(16);
  DECLARE b,c INT;
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id,data FROM test.t1;
  DECLARE cur2 CURSOR FOR SELECT i FROM test.t2;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

  OPEN cur1;
  OPEN cur2;

  REPEAT
    FETCH cur1 INTO a, b;
    FETCH cur2 INTO c;
    IF NOT done THEN
       IF b < c THEN
          INSERT INTO test.t3 VALUES (a,b);
       ELSE
          INSERT INTO test.t3 VALUES (a,c);
       END IF;
    END IF;
  UNTIL done END REPEAT;

  CLOSE cur1;
  CLOSE cur2;
END
```

Example taken from [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html).